# sort class by several date-fields

Tags: java, date, sorting

I have a class "entry" which has several date fields:

1. creationDate (always available)
2. manualSetDate (not always)
3. meetingDate (not always)

Now I'd like to sort the entries by first meetingDate (to have all entries of a meeting together), then or if not available at one entry by manualSetDate, and if they have the same meeting or if one entry has no manualSetDate also by the creationDate.

The difficulty is that many entries don't have a meeting- or a manualSetDate. So I have iterated over all (I hope so) possible combinations like:

```
Date relevant1; //at the end i compare both relevant dates
Date relevant2;
if e1.creationdate != null && e2.creationdate == null) 
  {relevant2 = e2.creationdate}...
if e1.creationdate == null && e2.creationdate != null) 
  {relevant2 = e2.creationdate}...
...
```

Which leads to high complexity

**Sort order:**

1. Meeting Date (if both have one)
2. ManualSetDate (if both have one)
3. CreationDate

I traversed over all combinations, but it seems to make mistakes...

Is there a better way to do the sorting? any ideas?

Comment: What is the code to do the sorting?

Comment: its just relevant1.compareTo(relevant2)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would make a function in my Entry that found the "relevant" date.  Then have your compareTo use that new function.  This way you aren't accounting for every possible combination as your code above does.

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>
{

   private Date getAvailableDate() 
   {
     if (meetingDate != null)
        return meetingDate;
     else if (manualSetDate != null)
        return manualSetDate;
     else
        return creationDate;
   }

   public int compareTo(Entry other)
   {
      return this.getAvailableDate().compareTo(other.getAvailableDate());
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks very much; now i have two ways; own comparator or your solution... which one is better?

Comment: Whether or not you make the class implement Comparable or you use your own Comparator does not matter so much - my point is to make your object smart enough to report it's own relevant date.  That will simplify whatever way you go about doing it.  But I'll say if you always need to maintain order, implement Comparable and use a SortedSet.  If you only sort once (or once in a while) create your own comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Better to write your own `Comparator` and implement `compare` method something like below code

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<DateEntry>{

@Override
public int compare(DateEntry o1, DateEntry o2) {

    int i = o1.creationDate.compareTo(o2.creationDate);
    if (i != 0) return i;

    if(o1.manualSetDate!=null&&o2.manualSetDate!=null)
    i = o1.manualSetDate.compareTo(o2.manualSetDate);
    if (i != 0) return i;

    if(o1.meetingDate!=null&&o2.meetingDate!=null)
        i = o1.meetingDate.compareTo(o2.meetingDate);
        if (i != 0) return i;

        return i;
}


}
```

And then Sort them like.

```
Collections.sort(list,new MyComparator ());
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to define order and then some library function to do actual sorting. I would also go for multiple early returns in compare method. Implementation is something like following:

```
public class Entry {
    ...
    public Date getMeetingDate() { return meetingDate;}
    public Date getManualSetDate() { return manualSetDate; }
    public Date getCreationDate() { return creationDate; }
}

public class EntryComparator implements Comparator<Entry> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2) {
        if (o1.getMeetingDate() != null && o2.getMeetingDate() != null) {
           int compared = o1.getMeetingDate().compareTo(o2.getMeetingDate());
           if (compared != 0) {
               return compared;
           }
        }
        if (o1.getManualSetDate() != null && o2.getManualSetDate() != null) {
            int compared = o1.getManualSetDate().compareTo(o2.getManualSetDate());
            if (compared != 0) {
                return compared;
            }
        }
        return o1.getCreationDate().compareTo(o2.getCreationDate());
    }
}

//and actual sorting:
List<Entry> entries ...
Collections.sort( entries, new EntryComparator() );
```